# Why was this custom flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

A few weeks ago, I raised a custom<sup>*</sup> flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305639/procedure-or-function-top100-has-too-many-arguments-specified/26483987#26483987) with the following comment:

> The OP posted a clarification (requested in comments) as an answer rather than amending his question. I've edited the question to include this material. – canon Oct 22 at 13:35

The flag was recently declined, citing:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

The answer was obviously a direct response to my [request for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305639/procedure-or-function-top100-has-too-many-arguments-specified/26483987#comment41279433_26305639). The post certainly wasn't an answer to the question.

What happened here? The only thing that comes to mind is that I made an assumption that the answer's author was the OP (despite differing account names). Is that it? Am I flagging improperly?

<sub><sup>*</sup> I felt that the post (without context) looked too much like a possible answer for a simple NAA flag.</sub>

Comment: I've no idea why it was declined. It shouldn't have been.

Comment: @animuson but doesn't it *appear* to be a NAA flag in the custom mod flags?

Comment: @codeMagic There is absolutely nothing wrong with using a custom flag to provide more information if you don't think the NAA flag will be clear to a moderator.

Comment: @animuson I get that but I think the message in the custom flag should be a little more direct as to why a custom flag is being used. As it stands, it looks to me like it is a plain old NAA flag as it says that the OP is using it for clarification (which is part of the NAA description). I get your point, but that would be my take on why it was declined.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're right, I shouldn't have declined it.

I declined it because from the moderator queue, I wasn't altogether sure what you wanted me to do.

The Moderator queue is a weird place.  By default we see very limited information about a post.

**We only see whether it's a question or answer based on the contextual actions we can take on that post.**

In this case, I thought I was looking at the question and thought that you had flagged the question.  This left me confused. My thought was, "Ok, so what do you want me to do?"

That's never a good place to leave [a monkey with a gun in there hands](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhO5TNU3fiJo&ei=lxhlVJmyLsqZgwSwloHwAw&usg=AFQjCNHioFltKlNU1sXqjPgVTaq5L2sgOQ&sig2=J-J8RFwR3Vs_gd2QEQ5fYA&bvm=bv.79189006,d.eXY).

[image]

Here are a few tips for when you leave a custom flag for a moderator:

- **Be actionable**. What do you want us to do? That should be your first statement.

  > Delete this post; OP posted more information as answer instead of editing question. I just edited the question.
- **Be concise**. Think of it like Twitter: If you have to tell me a story, chances are communication is going to get mixed up and it may not have the intended effect.
- **Use small words**. You may not realize it, but after processing 'other' flags for 30 minutes, it's really easy for words to jumble together.  From your perspective, your flag was the only flag I handled that day; from my perspective, your flag was one of hundreds.

All of that said; we do make mistakes (this is one such mistake) -- this answer isn't meant to excuse those, only to give the community some tips on how to make it easier for us to mark your flags as 'helpful' and take the action you want us to take.

Comment: If you reviewed 100 or more flags at that day, how can you still remember that you reviewed this flag?

Comment: @msrd0 the ones that are memorable (or confusing) are easy to remember.

Answer (score 9):

I bet this was an honest mistake on the part of a moderator. In my opinion, you aren't flagging improperly. As animuson said in the comments:

> There is absolutely nothing wrong with using a custom flag to provide more information if you don't think the NAA flag will be clear to a moderator.

You're giving them more information about what needs to be done (delete the answer) and why (you appended it to the original question).