# Why was my flag rejected, even though the post I see is not an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

A few days back I flagged the below post as it's not an answer to the question. Instead the user was posting his own problem in the answer box.

[Android IAB Error RPC:S-7 AEC-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476063/android-iab-error-rpcs-7-aec-0/28480353#28480353)

The good thing is that the post has been removed after that.

[image]

But when I look into my flag history it says "*a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*"

[image]

Now I don't know what to do with such kind of post.

1. Should I just add a comment?
2. Did I place the wrong flag?

Please, can anyone point me in the right direction so I can share the same with my other Stack Overflow friends here?

Comment: You're sure you flagged it as NAA?  If so, it'd seem very unusual that it would be rejected...

Comment: Yes @Makoto i flagged as "Not an Answer", I have just the snapshot of the same, Plz you can have look

Comment: Looks like an accidental decline to me. It happens, moderators are human too. The automatic comment from the Low Quality Review queue shows others agreed with your reading of the post.

Comment: It might be this, a moderator declined the flag confusing with another and later he realized that it was indeed not an answer and he deleted later so it might be a mistake so you can ignore that

Comment: _"Akela has missed," said the Panther._ Apparent moderator mistake

Answer (score 83, accepted):

All I can say is Sorry, this was a mistake.

It definitely is Not An Answer, obviously I was too quick when I cleared the flag - I use keyboard shortcuts - and I misclicked, realized it, and then deleted it.

My fault, no doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, I understand, I will keep flagging such post and **will give my hands to improve StackOverFlow** .

Comment: "I use keyboard shortcuts - and I mis*clicked*" aha!

Comment: He was try to write "mistyped", but.. he misclicked.

Comment: Misclicked...mistyped...same difference. :p

Comment: __kudos__ You accept your mistake. This is expected from all moderators.

Comment: @Satpal Does he have a choice? He can't play with time, even though he is moderator...

Comment: @Satpal Most moderators step to the plate and admit when they make a mistake.  This is not unusual.  We are humans and are prone to make mistakes when processing stuff.

Comment: You are first one I have seen, May be I need to be active more on meta.

Comment: @Satpal _"[modraters are just monkeys who has guns in there hands](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276778/621962)"_

Comment: @Satpal: just a heads-up: Bluefeet is a *she*. :-)