# Guidelines to being a prolific snitch

Tags: discussion, flags, help-vampire

Just the other day, I encountered an atrocious question from a user whose reputation would make you believe they'd know better than to ask such a question. They also didn't respond meaningfully to comments at all, didn't edit their question, and so on. They appeared to just want their code fixed.

A quick look at their profile showed this was about the 5th such question in the past 48 hours.

When I see such users, I sometimes flag them for moderator attention, as maybe a mod-message will let such users reconsider whether they're actually on the right site and interacting with it properly, because obviously they ignore us mere mortal users saying the same.

My flag was declined:

> please ask support related questions on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

So here it is: should we flag such users, or not?

Comment: DV/CV such questions leave a comment, there's no need to take additional actions.

Comment: "...user whose reputation..." - voting rings tough?

Comment: @Den I didn't suspect that in this case and other cases I've flagged. You just need to ask a handful of questions that aren't extremely poorly received, and you'll gain enough reputation and "trust" (as far as "the system" is concerned) to be declared scot-free.

Comment: @CodeCaster maybe this is not the case here, but I've seen lame answers getting rapid upvotes. Doesn't beat being first to answer a very basic question about a new language or tech though.

Comment: Also I think ```Snitch``` should be an SO/SE badge!

Comment: @Den yeah feel free to start a feature request for the `rat-on-a-twat` badge, which you earn for reporting three voting rings and two help vampires!

Comment: Not to be confused with the `golden snitch` badge, which is very difficult to get.

Comment: Compromised account?

Comment: @Robert compromised, sold, aneurysm, I have no idea.

Comment: @CodeCaster, did you mean "guidelines for handling someone who is being a prolific snitch"?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your flag was (emphasis mine):

> User is asking a streak of very poorly received, poorly researched and poorly worded questions, refusing to respond meaningfully to comments and never editing their question to add clarification. **Why didn't they hit a warning or question ban, or did they ignore that?**

The wording of your flag did not make it clear you were asking for us to mod-message the user (although, I still did in this circumstance).

Rather, it seemed your flag was *solely* about finding out why the user wasn't warned or question banned; which is not what flags are for, and as a moderator, I'm not privy to that information anyway.

---

In general, if you come across a user consistently posting low quality questions, then feel free to flag them. We can (and will) mod-message them; although I'm skeptical how much attention users actually pay to the warning.

As an aside, the automatic blocking mechanism does not seem effective in situations like you witnessed; users with a large number of questions, a few k of reputation, but where their most recent `x` questions have been incredibly poorly received. I'd like to see it give higher weight to the latter, and care less about the former, and actually block/ warn in such cases.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I didn't want to find out whether it happened, just wanted to make sure that it happened. To return to the question: are we encouraged to flag such behavior, and if so what would be a good text to put into it? I mean I didn't want the flag to sound "demanding", like _"Please warn this user"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster: In this situation, omitting your final sentence/ question would have been enough.

Comment: There's a peculiar ban reason that I've never seen on SO, but some mods might get fond of "suspended for low quality" (I'm sure is not like that, but has the same meaning)

Comment: @Hack-R http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36749/why-did-sceptical-become-skeptical-in-the-us

Answer (score 14):

Taken from [George Stocker's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276778/621962) to why *my* flag was declined... one of his guidelines for raising custom flags pertains to you:

> - **Be actionable**. What do you want us to do? That should be your first statement.
>
>   > Delete this post; OP posted more information as answer instead of editing question. I just edited the question.

If it's not perfectly clear what it is you want the moderator to do, it's likely that your flag will be declined. Part of that is a limitation of their review UI. I'd really recommend that you read his answer.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know what actions a moderator can take, and I don't want to determine their course of action. I should have worded the last sentence of the flag differently, but I hope you see I couldn't have begun with _"Ban this user"_ or _"Warn this user"_, because I don't know what the moderators usually do in such cases, nor what they already did in this case.

Comment: I concur; while this answer seems to come from canon (sorry, couldn't resist), I've heard other mods say "you don't have to tell us what to do, just explain the issue". Personally, I feel weird telling a moderator to take any specific action, partly because (as @CodeCaster said) I'm not sure of the options, and also because my judgment and perspective is very biased compared to a mod's.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've mostly followed George's advice and had good results. I don't recall a flag being denied because of a course of action I mentioned in the flag. In cases similar to yours I recall saying something like "maybe a notification from a moderator is in order". In other cases I'm less tentative. For instance, if I run into a question with a bounty that is a resource request I'll say "this question should be closed for being a resource request but cannot be closed by the community due to the bounty [...]" Ok, so I don't use the imperative voice like in George's example, but still...