# Do we need to instill some common sense into minds of users who keep asking bad questions?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

A lot of work is going into making [new users ask better questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard), and I can only applaud the effort. I'm [still wondering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326708/guidelines-to-being-a-prolific-snitch) though, what about "grandfathered" users who consistently show that they don't quite know what they're doing, who ignore or even get angry at comments asking for clarification and who time and again ask questions that have been asked before, or aren't really answerable, or scream *"I don't know what I'm doing"*?

The first time you encounter a question of theirs, it might be something like

- How can I make a nail?

Someone who made a nail once or twice comes along, answers the question with some basic smithery advice and everyone happily buzzes along. Then a couple of hours later, a new question arises:

- How can I straighten a bent nail?

And sure, someone knows how to do so, explains that, and the OP can continue on their project. A couple of hours later, or perhaps the next day, another question arises:

- My shed collapsed, please advise me to make the best nails?

Then some other users get riled up, they go dig through the OP's asking history, explain the XY Problem and finally the OP accepts that they were simply looking to buy a box of screws so they could put up their "Build-a-Shed™" shed-in-a-box.

A week or so passes, the OP moves on to another project, and lo and behold, there's a new question:

- Where can I dig up the best clay?

Here we go again. Someone answers with the locations of some high-quality clay deposits in their region, the OP goes to dig there and everyone is happy. A couple of hours later...

- How can I make my fire colder?

Because their vase cracked while baking it. And so on, and so on, while in the end, they were looking for a bucket to carry some water from one place or another.

Of course these silly examples are just that; in reality these questions are generally, at least marginally, on-topic. They're just extremely badly researched, often duplicated by many others, and show that the OP doesn't really have a clue what they're doing.

In the meantime, for each problem they cause or encounter during their work day, they take away resources from tens if not hundreds of users who could've spent their time answering better, unique questions.

Those users have a problem, but they don't realize that. They lack a certain "knack" you'd expect an "enthusiast developer" to have, namely the drive to better themselves, to come here and actually *learn* something as opposed to getting a single roadblock out of the way only to come to a full stop again at the next block, and having to ask yet another question in which they don't show any research or understanding.

But if you dare comment and ask them what their end goal is, they go on Reddit and Hacker News and complain what a bunch of know-it-alls we are and how we think we know everything better than them, the enlightened ones who just want their damn question answered so they can continue with their important work.

I simply really, really want to slap some common sense into such people, preferably with the three pound book on Advanced Pottery, Volume II.

In my flagging history I now have around ten users who behave like that, and yesterday a small drama ensued here on Meta (question now deleted, of course) where another one which I never encountered before was furious that their 1600th (!) vague, one-liner question was closed as a duplicate and downvoted for being unclear.

Now my question is: what, if anything, should I do about such users? Should I keep flagging their questions and hope the moderators can maybe enlighten them by sending a moderator message? Or should I simply ignore their questions? Are there other options I overlooked?

Of course, I know I can downvote and close vote their questions when I "organically encounter them", but that feels like mopping with the tap open (lacking a better idiom).

This is not really a duplicate of [What should we do about users who are proud to be help vampires?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258087/what-should-we-do-about-users-who-are-proud-to-be-help-vampires), because the accepted answer:

> The correct method of dealing with any question which is off-topic, is to vote to close it.
>   The correct method of dealing with any question which lacks research effort is to downvote it.

Does not work. So I'd rather consider this question to be a continuation of that one, because the question has not been satisfyingly answered.

The premise is also different. I'm not claiming these users willingly and knowingly act like a help vampire.

Comment: You don't happen to be talking about an undead person by any chance? Who may or may not be into psychedelic drugs? 24 hours a day? Not that we want to be naming names here, of course!

Comment: In the olden days, Jeff Atwood used to encourage us to flag such users for moderator attention. I doubt whether that would lead anywhere these days, though. I think I flagged a couple once but nothing came out of it if I remember correctly. At least nothing visible.

Comment: Just to bring a different spin on things, although I agree with main idea, if `Where can I dig up the bestest clay?` is not a duplicate on the site, is it not a valid question for SO? Regardless of whether it stemmed from a bad question? The old proverb of "I don't know what i don't know" comes to mind. Some people don't think down the road in their questions - that's not so much a SO problem, but a project management problem

Comment: You'd think that after downvoting and closing questions where appropriate, the user would've gotten a question ban before reaching 1600 questions.

Comment: @MattR `Where can I dig up the bestest clay? [Give me a list of places.]` is definitely off topic as a resource/list question. `What kind of factors should I be considering when exploring a site for mining clay?` would make a lot more sense, although not sure how well it would fare on SO these days (but then of course this type of user wouldn't ask that in the first place! That would be work!)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth nope, the algo doesn't seem to be affecting these kinds of users at all (and I suppose many achieved some degree of seniority before the question ban was invented so it was too late)

Comment: We will happily message users who consistently ask low-quality questions in response to flags, but I don't think I've ever seen this result in enlightenment. Time to come up with some alternative suggestions on how to impart common sense?

Comment: That user's behavior is an evolving story.  This morning he decided to rage-quit and changed the accepted answer on many dozens of his questions, picking the worst junk post he got.  Which is the usual way these users eventually hit the wall.  They just don't last, albeit that he did a lot longer than normal.  Whether that process can be shortcut, I seriously doubt it, resistance to good advice is a necessary character trait to get them into such a pickle.

Comment: @Hans I had opened my browser at home yesterday morning, and when I came back home I clicked that question's title - only to discover it was at like -60, deleted and all drama around it. I don't remember their name nor have I ever seen them before or after that question. That one user though is not the subject of my question here. I do understand it might be hard to short-circuit that effect. I'm definitely not looking to call users incompetent or to chase "help vampires" away; I'm looking for a positive solution from which all parties benefit.

Comment: `But if you dare comment and ask them what their end goal is, they go on Reddit and Hacker News ` The *real* problem isn't that, it's all of the other SO users who say "how dare you question a legit question, I'm upvoting that because you're being so mean to someone who doesn't know better".  I could care less about what Reddit thinks of me, it's the fact that these users are rewarded by the other SO users for posting this garbage, which lets them keep posting more of it.

Comment: `Should I keep flagging their questions and hope the moderators can maybe enlighten them by sending a moderator message?` Moderators have said that we should do this in the past, but I have not found it actually successful in the past, so I stopped bothering personally.  I think something more is needed, although I'm not sure if any more technical solutions would do much better.

Comment: @CodeCaster If I thought it would actually work, I'd be all for it.  Sadly I think it'd just result in people trying to upvote posts more "to offset those meanies".

Comment: @CodeCaster The opposite of the "Summer of Love"? Let's call it the "Winter of Discontent" - in which we diss bad content :-)  Not that it's going to happen.

Comment: Well removing the -1 cost of downvoting would help a bit.  There are far too many people who refuse to downvote bad content just because it costs them a whole Imaginary Internet Point to do it.

Comment: Maybe we should raise the bar for the upvote privilege - at least on SO.

Comment: Perhaps we need to look back to the sand & pearls analogy, and make a better picture that, unfortunately, we can't turn every grain into a pearl. Most questions just have to stay away from the sea of answerers. A fair amount of users are willing to step into low quality content, often to feel better that they helped one user, as well as for virtual points. This is intriguing, as I wonder whether passing the message that "most asked questions are no good" can backfire.

Comment: I'm still getting over that some users complained about being capped at 10 questions a day.  WTF?

Comment: @MartinJames Equally concerning is the users complaining about the 50 questions a month limit, or even those that just constantly hit it, even if they're not complaining about it.

Comment: @Servy I do occasionally wonder if it is possible to pass an IT course, or hold down a development job, solely by posting questions to SO and copying out the answers, ie. without any software skills at all:(

Comment: Also, the title of this questiion is... disturbing: Do we need to breed some common sense into users' - is it being suggested that we mate with them?

Comment: @Martin not a native speaker, but I didn't want to use "beat", instead something that radiates "grow" or the likes. Feel free to edit it into something more applicable.

Comment: @CodeCaster oh no, it's much more fun as it is:)

Comment: The times of "_a site for professional and enthusiast programmers_" are gone, this is what we have now, a day-care center for people who are just about to begin programming.

Comment: IMO, new users as well as users that have recently asked badly received question should have some daily limit applied. One question per day should be more than enough until they prove they are capable of asking proper questions. Yes, they can get question ban, but not before they manage to add nice collection of bad questions.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That's already in place.  It just doesn't work because it's easy enough to subvert, because even with some rate limiting there are still enough people asking bad questions, and most importantly because so many bad questions [get upvotes anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358678/do-we-need-to-breed-some-common-sense-into-users-who-keep-asking-bad-questions#comment527443_358678) and that prevents the automated systems from doing their job.

Comment: @Servy How is it possible that brand new user asks three questions in a day? I have seen such examples. And it is not like those questions are up voted. They are not necessarily down voted either, but if user is speedy Gonzales, he can ask bad questions before you can even blink.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The rate limit is 5 questions a day, as well as I believe several hours (I forget the specifics of that one, but you certainly can't post more than one question right away) between questions *if there are no poorly received questions*.  The rate limit goes down fast as soon as their are bad questions from the account or other users from the same internet connection.

Comment: @Tyler nope, the problem is that these users with 500+ questions on their record will never ever hit a question ban again.

Comment: @CodeCaster So then it sounds like what you really should be asking is a [meta-tag:feature-request] to adjust the question ban criteria.

Comment: I'd still like to see something like: [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) feature request I made introduced for new users or persistent offenders. If you get flagged as a user that needs to improve, you go through a few questions and judge them on their merits and have to attain a pass threshold before being allowed to post again. Similar to how audits test reviewers to make the right choice, a scheme like this would do the same for users that post bad content to explain what is deemed good or bad.

Comment: Well now that this is closed as a dupe: "flogging a dead horse" is the closest I have gotten to finding an alternative to *"mopping (the floor) with the tap/faucet open/running"*. But it just doesn't paint the same picture.

Comment: It would likely be difficult to tailor the question ban algorithm such that it would affect higher rep users equally. Such as my case, where all of my questions are negatively voted due to years of commenting on questions/answers that were downvoted. Though i guess it could be time gated, that and i don't ask questions so i wouldn't care if i were banned from doing so

Comment: @Tyler well it's a discussion question, I don't have a solution ready. Changing the question ban algorithm could be an option. Perhaps I'll post a couple of answers with the suggestions posted in comments so far, so users can vote on those.

Comment: @KevinB The question ban takes answers into account to.  Well received answers count for a lot less than a well received question (we don't know how much less, just that it's a lot less).  That's why you're not question banned.  The problematic users here are able to ask questions not because they've got thousands of good answers that keep them from the ban, but because lots of people have upvoted their bad questions in the past (and in my experience they often have a small number of extremely basic questions that are the top hit for a common term on google, and have a high score).

Comment: To me it sounds like you only want to help people who know exactly what needs to be done. In this case, they probably wouldn't be here. I think in order to make the community better, as a whole, you should foster a positive encouragement with the users you are mentioning. Perhaps with enough guidance they will be able to contribute back to the community when they have learned. From personal experience, I have noticed that this is not the most friendly community when you are trying to learn how to do something.

Comment: @Brad `I have noticed that this is not the most friendly community when you are trying to learn how to do something.` you're right, and in an ideal world SO maybe would be fulfilling that role too. But the reality is, resources - people willing to answer questions for free while competent enough to do so *well* - are limited. Most competent answerers want interesting, somewhat higher level q's to remain engaged long term. This is bound to exclude newbies to some degree. Teaching how to learn & research something is a specialist job really - that of educators, book authors, course designers...

Comment: @Pekka I understand what you are saying, but with the future in mind, perhaps it is worth taking a couple minutes to help the new people out, who, maybe read answers already but want more specific help. One time I asked for issue specific advice and was directed to a general page I had already read that did not help me and my answer was closed. The new people are the future of the community.

Comment: @Brad if it really were just a couple of people looking for a couple of minutes, sure. (And many of us frequently help out new users! We're nice people.) But in the big picture, there's tens of thousands of questions coming in every day, many of them of dismal quality or really trivial to Google. That is enough to paralyze *any* community. I'm not denying there is some genuine meanness or thoughtlessness in some users and comments around here sometimes, but much of the cold shoulder towards super basic stuff is just a community-wide defense mechanism that is essential for the place to survive.

Comment: _"To me it sounds like you only want to help people who know exactly what needs to be done."_ - no, but I want to help those that I see make a basic effort (and apply some basic common sense), rather than those that give you an "outsourced to SO" feeling.

Comment: @Brad no, I'm specifically talking about users who don't disclose the actual problem they're trying to solve, but who instead ask a vague question every few hours for every small hurdle they encounter while trying to solve a larger problem, and who don't appear to have any trouble-solving or researching skills whatsoever. I'm talking about users who have asked hundreds or thousands of questions, and don't respond meaningfully to comments asking for clarification by users who objectively have more experience in the subject than them. They're outsourcing their learning process to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodeCaster we have a saying in my country that translates to, _"not every cow belongs onto the ice"_ (referring to figure skating), meaning some might just need to find a different hobby (or profession), that suits their actual skillset more ... and I think that's simply the case with a lot of the kind of repeat offenders you're describing. Not sure what can be done about that, so I mostly resort to a close and/or down vote, and move on ...

Comment: Getting back to _deterring vampire enabling_, maybe (positive) reputation for answers should factor in the question quality. Or even limit the ability for lower-rep users to even write an answer, as long as the question doesn't get +x votes?

Comment: @Brad *"One time I asked for issue specific advice and was directed to a general page I had already read that did not help me and my answer was closed"* I would see that as re-enforcement that the page has my answer, and see it as a great reason to re-read over it more carefully. Then, if my problem isn't solved, potentially ask another question with what I learned from doing so such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: _"but with the future in mind, perhaps it is worth taking a couple minutes to help the new people out, who, maybe read answers already but want more specific help"_ - usually not a problem, provided they care to be specific about what answers they are referring to, and what exactly they are having trouble with.

Answer (score 5):

A summary of the suggested options:

#### Ignore them

It is an option. Just don't give them any more attention than other users.

That being said, I only found around ten such users, but given they ask questions on a daily basis and I only follow a handful of tags, there are bound to be more of them, and I do think it's a problem that should be addressed in one way or another.

#### Downvote and close-vote bad questions

I already do that and expect everyone else to too, however the kind of user I mean are "too big to fail" or "grandfathered" out of a question ban.

#### Keep flagging such users when you encounter them on an asking spree

Doesn't feel very effective, but the modmessages that might result from this might enlighten them.

### Change the question ban algorithm criteria

Granted a question ban yields the results we're looking for (namely fewer bad questions from repeat offenders), we could suggest a tweak to the question ban algorithm, for example letting it only consider the OP's most recently asked question in addition to the current criteria, and trigger if either would warrant a ban.

#### Rate limit for questions to increase again after a certain amount of questions

These users sometimes ask a question every couple of hours. This indicates they haven't researched or tried enough to solve their problem themselves. Limiting the rate at which they can ask questions could solve that, as it forces them to think longer before they can ask again.

Comment: Or perhaps split this out in an answer per solution, so the community can vote?

Comment: I would vote for "change the question ban algorithm criteria". It's clear that people can work themselves to a point where they are basically immune. It's a rare occurrence but the rarity of a problem does not say anything about how much damage can be done. If you repeatedly do wrong, you should be throttled. No exceptions, no immunities.