# Flags raised before edit processed after edit

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, declined-flags

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55117226/7910454) and [Md. Abu Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477792/md-abu-sayed) commented with an valid input. Now someone else comes along copies the entire comment character by character and puts it into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55117365/7910454) with *Go through it, it will work.* and NO further input or attribution whatsoever.

As I don't think this is appropriate behavior on SO I downvoted the answer, commented under the answer about my thoughts and flagged the answer for moderator intervention with  the comment:

*"low quality + copied comment from someone else"*

While I wait for my flag to be processed the guy who made the answer edits it (check the edit history) and replaces the stolen code with something of his own (still not correct or of the highest quality but no need for a moderator).

Now my flag gets processed and gets declined with the comment:

*"Who? I don't see any other answers that make this suggestion."*

---

Which leads me to my questions: **What if the reason of flagging was removed by an edit while the flag waited to be processed?** I think I was right to raise the flag at the time and the mod was right to decline it at the time he looked into it. As flags are needed for many things like review queues I don't want to lose my net helpful flags over things like this.

Comment: That's why we can edit, to fix this kinda stuff. That's not an issue at all. The declined flag isn't really a problem either, don't fret it :). And btw, copying a comment into an answer is allowed. As long as you provide attribution (here it wasn't done, so flagging was the right thing. At the time)

Comment: To be fair, I wouldn't have thought the code snippet `img{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}` required attribution. Flagging for moderation attention was not called for, IMO.

Comment: Regarding your question, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010).

Comment: @yivi Thank you. I didn't know I could retract a flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question

> What if the reason of flagging was removed by an edit while the flag waited to be processed?

is valid, and was answered in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381220/flags-raised-before-edit-processed-after-edit#comment677172_381220) by [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi): you are able to retract flags on posts (but [**not** comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/284827), yet):

> Regarding your question, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010).

---

Also very relevant here is the flag that you raised in the first place.

[The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117226/set-height-of-svg-to-line-height#comment96976080_55117226) by [Md. Abu Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477792/md-abu-sayed) wasn't much of an answer by itself (probably why it was posted as a comment):

> You can use the " img { display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; } "

[The first revision of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55117365/1) by [Sarabjit Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541352/sarabjit-singh), as you correctly identified, wasn't pretty much the same:

> Go through it, it will work.
>
> ```
> img{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
> ```

As [Patrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2417948/patrice) pointed out [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381220/flags-raised-before-edit-processed-after-edit#comment677168_381220), it's fine to copy a comment to an answer - provided that attribution is provided: see, for example, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304130/1364007) by [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) from [Is it correct to answer copying from comments by other users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304126/1364007) (emphasis mine):

> So first off, you'd need to determine if the author very clearly is basing their answer on a comment.  The example you gave is a very simple and easy problem with a single obvious and straightforward solution.  It's entirely plausible that the answerer came to the solution entirely independently.
>
> - If the answerer isn't independently coming up with the same solution, and they really are using the commenter's content, then **the only requirement be that they cite their source appropriately**.
> - There is no requirement that they add additional content (as long as it's clear what content is and isn't their own, and that **the content is cited appropriately**).
> - There is no obligation that the commentor be given time to write their own answer.  (I wouldn't even say that this is a convention.  If the commentor wanted to provide an answer, they would have; presumably they either don't feel the content is an answer, or don't want to provide an answer.)
> - There is no requirement that the answer be marked as Community Wiki. (This *is* a convention, but is by no means a requirement.)
>
> So the *only* reason to flag such an answer would be if **you have compelling evidence of plagiarism due to a lack of or improper citation.  Such a flag would need to indicate what is plagiarized, where the original source is, and evidence that it's copied.**  In this case, such a flag would be inappropriate as it's more than plausible that the answerer came to the solution independently.

The fact that the first edit of the answer was a pretty poor answer was probably why [Md. Abu Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477792/md-abu-sayed) didn't bother posting an answer in the first place - there was no explanation added, etc.

Your custom flag,

> low quality + copied comment from someone else

was rejected. Here it'd help to see this from the point of view of a moderator. The moderators (as a whole) have to deal with [thousands of flags a day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381074/1364007) and fatigue [is a real thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276778/1364007). Note that the caption for the "in need of moderator intervention" custom flag is

> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed!*

If I were in your situtation (before the answer was edited), and I were to raise a custom flag, I would have gone with something like:

> This answer is copy/pasted from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117226/set-height-of-svg-to-line-height#comment96976080_55117226) by [Md. Abu Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477792/md-abu-sayed) five minutes earlier without attribution: only "Go through it, it will work." was added.

This gives the moderator some key information:

- A link to the comment in question. As the answer was edited before the moderator got to it, they could follow the link to the comment and would see that it differed from the answer in the state that they got to it. I would *assume* that the moderator would then go to [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55117365/revisions) for that post, which clearly shows that your flag was valid (when it was posted). Also, moderators [have to click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85469/284827) "show deleted comments" to see them, so if the comment was deleted, you'd have posted a link to it, which would help them find it.
- Context in the form of the time between the comment and the answer: the comment was posted<sup>*</sup> at `2019-03-12 08:45:26Z` and the answer at `2019-03-12 08:50:38Z` (over five minutes later), so either the answerer didn't read the comments before posting their answer and came to the same answer independently, or they *knowingly* copied the text without attribution.

The moderator handling your flag could then see that your flag was valid at the time and could make more of an informed decision. Moderator flags are either [marked as helpful or declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203072/284827) but they are at liberty to mark your flag as 'helpful' even if they don't do anything, for instance if the issue has resolved itself or if no action is needed, but the flag was raised in good faith.

In other words, if you are *specific and detailed* in your custom flag, you'll have a much better chance of it not being declined - even in this case. While the onus isn't on you to constantly monitor the answer to check for changes then retract it, adding more details would probably have made a big difference to the outcome here.

---

<sup>*</sup> Anywhere that you see a time on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange sites in general), you can hover over it to get the timestamp.